# How to close framed pop up window with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to close popped up window of this page http://zerohedge.talking-forex.com/live.html

Does anyone know how to do that, well it is not easy obviously, but nevertheless anyone?

If selenium not powerful enought for that task, please recommend another tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you want to interact with is inside a frame (named 'content'). You need to tell selenium to switch to it. The following python code works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://zerohedge.talking-forex.com/live.html")
driver.switch_to_frame("content");
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-icon-closethick").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

...That should be fairly straightforward:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-icon-closethick")).click();
```

Comment: should be, but its harder then it looks, I bet you didn't try your code in action :).